# Android list view with small circles & line at left side throughout the list?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build UI like as shown in below image.

[image]

I see this kind of ui component is possible using a list view, but how do I have a small circle & lines connecting circles ?

How should i achieve same?

Answer (score 0):

For every item the listview do the following:

- Add a layout with to the left side. In this layout you will place the new elements (dot and line(s)).
- Draw a colored dot in the middle
- Check if the item is the first in the list, if so, only draw a line from the dot to the bottom of the item view
- Check if the item is the last in the list, if so, only draw a line from the dot to the top of the item view
- If the item is neither the first nor the last in the list, draw lines from the dot to the top and from the dot to the bottom of the item view.